# uniform distribution question: cdf

Tags: probability

> A little boy plays outside in the yard. On his own he would come back
> inside at a random time uniformly distributed on the interval [0,1].
> (Let us take the units to be hours.) However, if the boy is not back
> inside in 45 minutes, his mother brings him in. Let X be the time when
> the boy comes back inside.

I know the CDF is x if 0 < x < 3/4 and 1 if x > 3/4.

I also know the PDF is 1 for 0 < x < 3/4 because it's uniform distribution. What's the PDF for x > 3/4? What's bizarre is that I know $f(x) \times \epsilon$ is approximately equal to the probability at x and I want to convey that the probability the boy goes in between 3/4 and 1 is exactly 1 for every value in this interval because the boy is definitely inside due to mom.

Also I know we can let x = 3/4 (and make it a discrete r.v.) but I want to leave it continuous because I need way more practice with continuous

Comment: You are combining a continuous probability distribution with a discrete probability distribution.  There is not ordinary "density" function for $x\gt 3/4$ once the mother is assumed to intervene, other than to introduce a "generalized" density function (a Dirac delta function) that acts at $x=3/4$.

Answer (score 1):

The requested CDF is

$$F_X(x)=x\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;0.75)}(x)+\mathbb{1}_{[0.75;+\infty)}(x)$$

As you can see (do a drawing of F) there is a "jump" in $x=0.75$. This jump has a height as 0.25 which is the probability of his Mum to get it in.